# Customizing g:paginate to Prepend "Page x of y"

Tags: grails, pagination, taglib

I have a simple scenario where I'm using g:paginate to do pagination, but next to it I need to say "Page x of y" next to the actual pages.  For example, if I'm on page 3 out of 10 pages total, I want to have (obviously pages other than 3 would be links):

```
Page 3 of 10 << 1 2 3 4 .. 10 >>
```

There doesn't appear to be a way to do this out of the box, and I'm wondering if anyone has ever come across this or can think of some way to pull that information out of the tag, like if I made a custom taglib that pulled the appropriate properties out of g:paginate (just as an idea), or any other solution would be okay too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're providing the view with a total count, and assigning `params` a `max` and `offset` value in your controller, I think you would have everything need to do the calculations for a "x of total" message.

Basically the snippet to generate the "x of toal" is:

```
Page ${((params.offset as Long) / (params.max as Long)) + 1} of ${instanceTotal}
```

You could assign this to the `prev` attribute in the paginate tag, but unfortunately the prev does not show up when you're on the first page. So I think you're best to either extend this functionality in a custom tag, or use the snippet above outside of the paginate tag.